# Displaying two legends inline in html form

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to add two legends at the top of the form. I need both legends to display inline as opposed to one stacked above the other.

Like so:

-----legendOne---LegendTwo-----

How do I achieve that layout in CSS?

Here's the current CSS setting:

```
legend {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #00BCE6;
  border: 1px solid #00BCE6;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the legend to `float:left` and add some `margin-top`, like this:

```css
fieldset {
    margin-top:25px; 
}

legend {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #00BCE6;
  border: 1px solid #00BCE6;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  float:left;
  margin-top:-25px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>legend 1</legend>
    <legend>legend 2</legend>
    <br />
    Input <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

The result looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4ekec329/ (I also added some `margin-top` to the `fieldset` and needed to add a line break after the legends).
This is tested in FF 41, IE 11 and Chrome 46, but I can't guarantee it'll look like this in other browsers, too.

A `fieldset` normally contains only one `legend`, so this isn't standard HTML and may break in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could place 2 `span` elements in the legend then style those instead:

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend><span>first</span><span>second</span></legend>
```

```css
legend {
    margin-left:25px;
}
legend span {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;  
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #00BCE6;
  border: 1px solid #00BCE6;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
legend span+span {
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend><span>first</span><span>second</span></legend>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
</fieldset>
```